# set.difference no matter newline in python

Tags: python, set

I am working in a script to compare two text files. To achieve this I am using the Python Set | difference(). I create a set for the content of every file like the code below and it works. Well, almost works. I found out that no matter if a line is in both files, while the line has no '\n' the comparison discard it. Since I cannot control if a line will have '\n' or not and seems this issue is very detailed I came here to ask if someone has face this before.

```
with open(files_to_extract, 'r') as file1:

    with open(downloaded_files, 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).difference(set(file2))

same.discard('\n')

with open(not_found_files, 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
        print(line)
```

files_to_extract set:

```
{'FromXXXX_Time20180630_165129.zip\n', 'FromXXXX_Time20180630_1637344.zip', 'FromXXXX_Time20180630_163734.zip\n', 'FromXXXX_Time20180630_170523.zip\n'}
```

downloaded_files set:

```
{'FromXXXX_Time20180630_165129.zip\n', 'FromXXXX_Time20180630_163734.zip\n', 'FromXXXX_Time20180630_170523.zip\n'}
```

not_found_files file is empty and supposed to contain

```
FromXXXX_Time20180630_1637344.zip
```

but it is discarded.

Is there a way to compare no matter if there is a '\n' or not? Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `FromXXXX_Time20180630_163734.zip\n` item in your `downloaded_files` actually has one less `4` than the `FromXXXX_Time20180630_1637344.zip` in your `files_to_extract`, so it would not match even if `\n` was not an issue.

To compare strings with no regard to the trailing `\n`, all you would need to do here is to strip it from all strings before adding them to the sets:

```
same = set(map(str.rstrip, file1)).difference(set(map(str.rstrip, file2)))
```

Comment: You know that converting file2 into a set is useless right?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can compare them by removing the \n...

```
foo="foo\n"
foo2="foo"
foo=foo.replace('\n','')
foo2=foo2.replace('\n','')
foo==foo2
```

> True

Do that for everything and you've got it.